Alexa Skill Fails to Respond Despite Successful Build and Deployment
I'm trying to write an Alexa skill using the Alexa Developer Console. Here are the details of my setup:

Skill Name: testone
Locale: en-GB
Model: Custom
Alexa Hosted: Node.js
Started from scratch, which provided the Hello World Lambda code

Here's the process I followed:

Clicked 'Create' and the skill built successfully.
Changed the invocation name to "test one"
Deployed the code from the Code tab.
Rebuilt the skill, which also completed successfully.
Went to the Test tab, set the environment to Development, and entered "open test one."

However, every time I test the skill, Alexa responds with "Sorry, I don't know that" or a similar message, indicating that the skill is found but not responding correctly.
I've tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

Testing on different browsers and PCs.
Changing the invocation names.
Following several tutorials, including this one, although it doesn't cover code deployment (I tried both with and without code deployment).

Am I missing something in the process, or is there a new preferred method for developing Alexa skills? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you
I expected alexa to respond with the launch phrase defined in the std lamdba code - 'Welcome, you can say Hello or Help. Which would you like to try?'

Then today its works as expected.  Not sure if I did something different or if something has been changed.

And the problem returns. Puzzling....

Try a more distinctive invocation name. And your steps 3 and 4 should be swaped, build first, then deploy.
